# Sandbox something like privileges problems and SPGroup.Users

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts

`SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` is not avaible for sandbox, and this make me some problems.

```
SPGroupCollection _collGroups = _web.Groups;
foreach (SPGroup _Group in _collGroups)
{
    foreach (SPUser _User in _Group.Users /*<--ERROR HERE*/)
    {
        //CODE//
    }
}
```

This part of code generate me error with access, when it is executed by user that is not site colletions administrator. The problem is that, I need to get list of all users of the current site collection and send them notifications via ajax control. Above code is executed in aspx page inside webpart. Is there any way to get users lists without grant a permission to site collection administration? I need this list only for putting users, and removing them from two fields with buttons in the docLibrabry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> foreach (SPUser _User in _web.SiteUsers)

from that scope

> SiteUsers

solve ther issue